# How to sum the values of all the textboxes with same class which are generated using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to sum of all the values of textboxes generated using ajax. I have the textboxes with classname `adminhours`and these textboxes are generated using ajax. The sum should be displayed in another textbox on the change event of the textbox with class `adminhours`. The sum should be multiplied with the admin rate textbox. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="timecardstepcontainer">
    <table class="widefat" style="width:100%" id="steponetable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email2(payment)</th>
                <th>Class Rate</th>
                <th>Admin Rate</th>
                <th>Week</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Comment</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="txtuser" id="txtuser">
                    <option>--select--</option>
                                        <option value="2">nitinjohnson2000</option>

                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txtemail2" style="width:100%;" readonly=""></td>
                <td width="5%"><input type="text" name="txtclassrate" style="width:80px;" readonly=""></td>
                <td width="5%"><input type="text" name="txtadminrate" style="width:80px;" readonly=""></td>
                <td><!--<input type="text" name="txtweek" id="txtweek" />-->
                    <select name="txtweek" id="txtweek">
                        <option>--select--</option>
                                                <option>08-31-2015</option>
                                                <option>09-07-2015</option>
                                                <option>09-14-2015</option>
                                                <option>09-21-2015</option>
                                                <option>09-28-2015</option>
                                                <option>10-05-2015</option>
                                                <option>10-12-2015</option>
                                                <option>10-19-2015</option>
                                            </select>
                </td>
                <td><label id="txtstatus">Not Saved</label></td>
                <td><textarea name="txtcomment"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div class="timecardstepcontainer" id="steptwotable">
        <table class="widefat" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Session</th>
                    <th>Day of week</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Pre-Assigned</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>
                    <th>Present</th>
                    <th>Late Arrival</th>
                    <th>Expense</th>
                    <th>Admin Hours</th>
                    <th>Comments</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fall 2015 - Bethany Elementary Chess Program - Plano ISD</td>
                    <td>Wed</td>
                    <td>09-02-2015</td>
                    <td>Y</td>
                    <td>2015-09-09</td>
                    <td>2015-12-12</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="presentdays[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="latedays[]"></td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="admin_hours[]" class="adminhours" value="0" style="width:50px;"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="item_comment" style="width:80px;"></td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fall 2015 - Ashley Elementary Chess Program - Frisco ISD</td>
                        <td>Mon</td>
                        <td>08-31-2015</td>
                        <td>Y</td>
                        <td>2015-09-14</td>
                        <td>2015-12-12</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="presentdays[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="latedays[]"></td>
                        <td>15</td><td><input type="text" name="admin_hours[]" class="adminhours" value="0" style="width:50px;"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="item_comment" style="width:80px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fall 2015 - Bledsoe Elementary Chess Program - Frisco ISD</td>
                        <td>Wed</td>
                        <td>09-02-2015</td>
                        <td>Y</td>
                        <td>2015-09-16</td>
                        <td>2015-12-12</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="presentdays[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="latedays[]"></td>
                        <td>15</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="admin_hours[]" class="adminhours" value="0" style="width:50px;"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="item_comment" style="width:80px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Fall 2015 - Anderson Elementary Chess Program - Frisco ISD</td>
                        <td>Mon</td>
                        <td>08-31-2015</td>
                        <td>Y</td>
                        <td>2015-09-21</td>
                        <td>2015-12-12</td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="presentdays[]"></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="latedays[]"></td>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="admin_hours[]" class="adminhours" value="0" style="width:50px;"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="item_comment" style="width:80px;"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="timecardstepcontainer">
        <table class="widefat" style="width:100%" id="stepthreetable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Day</th>
                    <th>Classes $</th>
                    <th>Late $</th>
                    <th>Expense</th>
                    <th>Admin</th>
                    <th>Approved Adjustment</th>
                    <th>Approved Comment</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="text" name="number_of_classes" value="4" style="width:50px;" readonly=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="totalclasses" value="40" readonly=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" value="" id="latecharges" readonly=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="totalexpense" value="40" readonly=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="totaladminrate" value="0" readonly=""></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="approved_adjustment" id="approved_adjustment" style="width:50px;"></td>
                    <td><textarea name="approver_comment"></textarea></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="timecardstepcontainer">
        <table class="widefat" style="width:100%">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>Total</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="finaltotal" id="finaltotal" readonly=""></td>
                <td>Approved Total</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="approvedtotal" id="approvedtotal" readonly=""></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="alldata" id="alldata" value="16,15,17,14">
    <div class="timecardstepcontainer">
        <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="addtimecard" value="Save" class="button button-primary button-large"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>

</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("select[name='txtuser']").change(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:ajaxurl,
            type:'post',
            data:{action:'timecardapp_manage_timecard_stepone',user_id: jQuery("#txtuser").val()},
            success: function(response){    
                var data=JSON.parse(response);              
                jQuery("input[name='txtemail2']").val(data.email2);
                jQuery("input[name='txtclassrate']").val(data.class_rate);
                jQuery("input[name='txtadminrate']").val(data.admin_rate);
            }
        });
    });
    jQuery("#txtweek").change(function(){
        if(jQuery("select[name='txtuser'] option:selected").text()=='--select--'){          
            alert("Please select a user first to proceed");
            return false;
        } else {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:ajaxurl,
                type:'post',
                data:{action:'timecardapp_manage_timecard_stepone',user_id: jQuery("#txtuser").val()},
                success: function(response){    
                    var data=JSON.parse(response);                  
                    var alldata = new Array();                  
                    var currentweek = jQuery("#txtweek option:selected").text();
                    var days_date = new Array();
                    function pad(str) {
                      return ("0"+str).slice(-2);
                    }
                    function getNextDay(str) { 
                      var parts = str.split("-");
                      var mon_day = new Date(parts[2], parts[0] - 1, parseInt(parts[1], 10) + 0, 12, 0, 0, 0);
                      var tue_day = new Date(parts[2], parts[0] - 1, parseInt(parts[1], 10) + 1, 12, 0, 0, 0);
                      var wed_day = new Date(parts[2], parts[0] - 1, parseInt(parts[1], 10) + 2, 12, 0, 0, 0);
                      var thu_day = new Date(parts[2], parts[0] - 1, parseInt(parts[1], 10) + 3, 12, 0, 0, 0);
                      var fri_day = new Date(parts[2], parts[0] - 1, parseInt(parts[1], 10) + 4, 12, 0, 0, 0);
                      days_date[0] = ""+pad(mon_day.getMonth()+1)+"-"+ pad(mon_day.getDate())+"-"+mon_day.getFullYear();
                      days_date[1] = ""+pad(tue_day.getMonth()+1)+"-"+ pad(tue_day.getDate())+"-"+tue_day.getFullYear();
                      days_date[2] = ""+pad(wed_day.getMonth()+1)+"-"+ pad(wed_day.getDate())+"-"+wed_day.getFullYear();
                      days_date[3] = ""+pad(thu_day.getMonth()+1)+"-"+ pad(thu_day.getDate())+"-"+thu_day.getFullYear();
                      days_date[4] = ""+pad(fri_day.getMonth()+1)+"-"+ pad(fri_day.getDate())+"-"+fri_day.getFullYear();

                    }

                    var currentweek = jQuery("#txtweek option:selected").text(), // no values available
                    next_day = new Date(); // or some other default

                    if (currentweek && currentweek.indexOf("--") == -1) { // not the first
                      next_day=getNextDay(currentweek);
                    }

                    var trHTML = '';
                    var number_of_classes = 0;
                    var totalexpense = 0;
                    var totaladminhours = 0;

                    jQuery.each(data.final_data, function (i, item) {
                        if(item.event_title == 'Admin'){
                            //Monday
                            trHTML += '<tr>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.event_title+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>Mon</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+days_date[0]+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>Y</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.start_date+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.end_date+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.expense_allowance_value+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td><input type="text" name="admin_hours[]" class="adminhours" value="'+item.hours_allowed+'" style="width:50px;" /></td>';
                            trHTML += '<td><input type="text" name="item_comment" style="width:80px;" /></td>';
                            trHTML += '</tr>';

                            //Tuesday
                            trHTML += '<tr>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.event_title+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>Tue</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+days_date[1]+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>Y</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.start_date+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.end_date+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.expense_allowance_value+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td><input type="text" name="admin_hours[]" class="adminhours" value="'+item.hours_allowed+'" style="width:50px;" /></td>';
                            trHTML += '<td><input type="text" name="item_comment" style="width:80px;" /></td>';
                            trHTML += '</tr>';

                            //Wednesday
                            trHTML += '<tr>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.event_title+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>Wed</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+days_date[2]+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>Y</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.start_date+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.end_date+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.expense_allowance_value+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td><input type="text" name="admin_hours[]" class="adminhours" value="'+item.hours_allowed+'" style="width:50px;" /></td>';
                            trHTML += '<td><input type="text" name="item_comment" style="width:80px;" /></td>';
                            trHTML += '</tr>';

                            //Thursday
                            trHTML += '<tr>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.event_title+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>Thu</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+days_date[3]+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>Y</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.start_date+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.end_date+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.expense_allowance_value+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td><input type="text" name="admin_hours[]" class="adminhours" value="'+item.hours_allowed+'" style="width:50px;" /></td>';
                            trHTML += '<td><input type="text" name="item_comment" style="width:80px;" /></td>';
                            trHTML += '</tr>';

                            //Friday
                            trHTML += '<tr>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.event_title+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>Fri</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+days_date[4]+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>Y</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.start_date+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.end_date+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.expense_allowance_value+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td><input type="text" name="admin_hours[]" class="adminhours" value="'+item.hours_allowed+'" style="width:50px;" /></td>';
                            trHTML += '<td><input type="text" name="item_comment" style="width:80px;" /></td>';
                            trHTML += '</tr>';

                            alldata.push(item.session_id);

                        } else {
                            trHTML += '<tr>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.event_title+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.day_of_week+'</td>';
                            if(item.day_of_week=='Mon'){
                                trHTML += '<td>'+days_date[0]+'</td>';
                            }
                            if(item.day_of_week=='Tue'){
                                trHTML += '<td>'+days_date[1]+'</td>';
                            }
                            if(item.day_of_week=='Wed'){
                                trHTML += '<td>'+days_date[2]+'</td>';
                            }
                            if(item.day_of_week=='Thu'){
                                trHTML += '<td>'+days_date[3]+'</td>';
                            }
                            if(item.day_of_week=='Fri'){
                                trHTML += '<td>'+days_date[4]+'</td>';
                            }
                            trHTML += '<td>Y</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.start_date+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.end_date+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="presentdays[]" /></td>';
                            trHTML += '<td><input type="checkbox" name="latedays[]" /></td>';
                            trHTML += '<td>'+item.expense_allowance_value+'</td>';
                            trHTML += '<td><input type="text" name="admin_hours[]" class="adminhours" value="'+item.hours_allowed+'" style="width:50px;" /></td>';
                            trHTML += '<td><input type="text" name="item_comment" style="width:80px;" /></td>';
                            trHTML += '</tr>';

                            number_of_classes++;
                            totalexpense = +totalexpense + +item.expense_allowance_value;
                            totaladminhours = totaladminhours + item.hours_allowed;



                        }
                        alldata.push(item.session_id);
                    });

                    jQuery('#steptwotable').find('tbody').empty();
                    jQuery('#steptwotable').find('tbody').append(trHTML);

                    var totalclasses = number_of_classes * jQuery("input[name='txtclassrate']").val();
                    var totaladminrate = totaladminhours * jQuery("input[name='txtadminrate']").val();
                    var trHTML2 = '';
                    trHTML2 += '<tr>';
                    trHTML2 += '<td><input type="text" name="number_of_classes" value="'+number_of_classes+'" style="width:50px;" readonly /></td>';
                    trHTML2 += '<td><input type="text" name="totalclasses" value="'+totalclasses+'" readonly /></td>';
                    trHTML2 += '<td><input type="text" value="" id="latecharges" readonly /></td>';
                    trHTML2 += '<td><input type="text" name="totalexpense" value="'+totalexpense+'" readonly /></td>';
                    trHTML2 += '<td><input type="text" name="totaladminrate" value="'+totaladminrate+'" readonly /></td>';
                    trHTML2 += '<td><input type="text" name="approved_adjustment" id="approved_adjustment" style="width:50px;"  /></td>';
                    trHTML2 += '<td><textarea name="approver_comment"></textarea></td>';
                    trHTML2 += '</tr>';
                    jQuery('#stepthreetable').find('tbody').empty();
                    jQuery('#stepthreetable').find('tbody').append(trHTML2);
                    jQuery("#alldata").val(alldata);

                    var the_final_total = +totalclasses + +totalexpense - jQuery("#latecharges").val() + +totaladminrate;
                    jQuery("#finaltotal").val(the_final_total);
                }
            });
        }
    });

});
jQuery(document).on("keyup change", ".adminhours", function() { 
    var latecharge;
    var admincharge;
    var adminhours=jQuery(".adminhours");

    if(jQuery("#latecharges").val().length > 0){
        latecharge=jQuery("#latecharges").val();
    } else {
        latecharge=0;
    }

    if(jQuery("input[name='totaladminrate']").val().length > 0){
        admincharge=jQuery("input[name='totaladminrate']").val();
    } else {
        admincharge=0;
    }
    alert(adminhours.length);
    if(jQuery(".adminhours").val().length > 0){
        for(var i = 0; i < adminhours.length; i++){
            adminhours= +adminhours+ + +jQuery(adminhours[i]).val();        
        }
    } else {
        adminhours=0;
    }
    var thefinaltotal = +admincharge + +jQuery("input[name='totalclasses']").val() + +jQuery("input[name='totalexpense']").val() - latecharge;
    jQuery("input[name='totaladminrate']").val(adminhours*jQuery("input[name='txtadminrate']").val());
    jQuery("input[name='finaltotal']").val(thefinaltotal);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic to get all elements with class `.adminhours` should not check with val in selector `if(jQuery(".adminhours").val().length > 0)`. I have updated your code below :

```
var totalAdminhours = 0;
if(jQuery(".adminhours").length > 0){
        jQuery(".adminhours").each(function () {
            totalAdminhours += totalAdminhours + jQuery(this).val();        
        });
    } else {
        totalAdminhours = 0;
    }
```